# Get notify-send to clear itself from notification tray

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnome

I am running gnome 3.24.2. When I run notify-send from bash, it seems that the notification is shown for a default of 5 seconds, as expected. But then it seems to linger in the notification tray forever until the user decides to clear it. Is there a way for it to just expire completely without hanging out in the notification tray, much like a popup?

current behaviour:

1. show notification for 5s
2. remain in notification message tray

expected behaviour:

1. show notification for 5s
2. dissappear from notification tray

I am struggling to find resources that help understand how to use notify-send. notify-send --help is not particularly useful either.

Answer (score 7):

This will provide the behavior you're looking for:

```
notify-send --hint=int:transient:1 hello
```